# ¿Cómo agrego un valor en medio de un array bidimensional?

Tags: php, php5

mi objetivo es añadir el array titulos dentro de titulos1 con la condición que no se agregue ni al principio(array_unshift) ni al final(array_push), sino en medio (desplazando los indices del array titulos1)

tengo este codigo:

```
$titulos = array(array('CICLO', '',' ','',''));
$titulos1 = array(array('1','2','3','4','5'),array('a','b','c','d','e'));
```

la salida es:

```
titulo1:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
            [4] => e
        )
titulo:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CICLO
            [1] => 
            [2] =>  
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )
```

Lo que busco es:

```
titulo1:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 4
                [4] => 5
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => CICLO
                [1] => 
                [2] =>  
                [3] => 
                [4] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
                [2] => c
                [3] => d
                [4] => e
            )
```

El problema que vengo afrontando es que recorro un array con muchos valores con while y dentro de este tengo la necesidad de imprimir en medio de un array y pues... necesito ejecutar lo ya mencionado anteriormente

intenté reemplazando los valores dentro del array pero por algún motivo no me funciona y me parece complicado.

```
$i=0;
    while ($i<$row_count)
    {
    if ($resultados[$i][0]=='13')
              {
                $prime2=array($nombreidioma.' INTERMEDIO','','','','');
                $resultados1[$i+1][0]= $prime2;
                $resultados1[$i+1]=$resultados1[$i];
                //break;

                $temp=$resultados1[$i+1];
                for($j=$i+1;$j<=$row_count-1-$i;j+1)
                {
                  $resultados1[$j]= $prime2;
                  $resultados1[$j+1]= $temp;
                  $resultados1[$j+2]= $resultados1[$j+1];   
                }
}
```

Agradeceré toda la ayuda posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes utilizar la funcion **array_splice** de esta manera.

```
array_splice( $titulos1, 1, 0, $titulos );
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Eres un genio!
me fue perfecto, gracias!

Comment: Que bueno poder ayudarte.